# Displaying related table data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm learning vuejs and using laravel for the backend api. I have the following tables

articles, articles_translations and i mentioned their relations in their models

i created a vue component fpr articles

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-for="article in articles" :key="article.articles">
        <h4>{{article.translations}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        layout: 'basic',

        computed: mapGetters({
          locale: 'lang/locale'
        }),
        data: function () {
            return {
                articles: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            var app = this;
            console.log(this.locale);
            axios.get('/api/articles')
                .then(response => {
                  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                  this.articles = response.data
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  this.errors.push(e)
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

this displays [ { "id": 1, "article_id": 1, "title": "This is an example title", "subtitle": "this is a subtitle", "content": "this is the content", "locale": "en", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ] as expected

[image]

I want to display the articles in this format

1. article title article
2. article subtitle
3. article content

In blade i normally do {{ $article->article_translations->title }} to fetch related table data. How does this work in vue? How to display the data in the format i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by what you posted you could get the article translation attributes like this:

```
<div v-for="article in articles" :key="article.articles">
    <div v-for="translation in article.translations">
        <h4>{{ translation.title }}</h4>
        {{ translation.subtitle }}
        {{ translation.content }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically add another for loop, since your translations are in an array. And then simply display the attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

just use the Laravel query builder the inner join will help to your problem this is a quick example then you will receive the collection of properties or your object.

explanation: users table get a User object, people table is related to the user with user_id column. just need to join tables related and get this result[image]

```
$users = DB::table('people')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=' ,'people.user_id')
        ->select('users.*',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'street_address',
            'city',
            'state',
            'contact_phone'
        )->get();

    return response()->json(['data' => $users], 200);
```